# How use kotlinx.serialization decode generics list?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

i have a json like this:

```json
{"code":200,"msg":"111",data:[{"name":"va","list":[{"code":"11"}]},{"name":"va","list":[{"code":"11"}]}]}
```

my class like this:

```kotlin
@Serializable
class ServerResponse<T> {
    @SerialName(value = "code")
    var code = 0

    @SerialName(value = "msg")
    var msg: String? = null

    @SerialName(value = "data")
    var data: T? = null
        private set
}

@Serializable
data class PluginInfo(
    @SerialName(value = "name")
    val name: String,
    @SerialName(value = "list")
    val list: MutableList<PluginConfig>
)

@Serializable
data class PluginConfig(
    @SerialName(value = "code")
    val code: String
)
```

when i use JSON.decodeFromString:

```kotlin
val response =
                json.decodeFromString<ServerResponse<MutableList<PluginInfo>>>(pluginInfoJson)
```

this throw exception:

kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 271: Expected quotation mark '"', but had '1' instead at path: $.data[0].

Comment: data property needs to be quoted "data", and also - why are you using ServerResponse instead of Response?

Comment: yes,it is ServerResponse,I edit it

Comment: @Gray ,I tried your example with data property quoted, and it worked.

Comment: @Barracuda I solved it, because my field type not match,  String>Int